# iphone : How does multitasking work on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, file-upload, background, multitasking

I am new in iPhone application and have no iPhone to play with. I have looked online about iPhone 4 has multitasking but previous iPhone doesn't. In previous version iPhone, is there no chance of having application running certain task at the background.

On the internet, I saw some link saying iPhone only allow app run in the background within 10 mins or something before it terminated the application. Does this mean iPhone 4 or earlier version.

I am asking these question because I want to write an app that require user to upload the files to the server but don't want to stop the users to do other things: Using other application while our application sending file at the background.

Any help?

Comment: what kind of files are on the iPhone that needs too much time to upload? Files inside your iPhone app should be small.

Comment: A collection of photos waiting for upload to the server. Just in case it may take sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the iPhone 3GS also supports background process and multitasking.

Its true that when [Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4) it will only work for 10 min if you app has been backgrounded.

So if you implement it this way the file your app is uploading will continue to be upload if the app is backgrounded. but be aware of the 10 min restriction.

Also the simulator is not the best way to test these thinks because it does not really emulate  an iPhone, it just more of a host for iOS application.

Comment: To make sure i understand, so including iPhone 4 the background task need to be performed within 10 mins..

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPad and third generation of iPod touch running iOS 4.0 or higher will able to preform a task in background for about 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

you should read this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4

Answer (score 0):

There is, AFAIK, no way to perform arbitrary background tasks beyond a restricted set of things explicitly offered by the framework (e.g., tracking GPS events). Your app gets a chance to put itself into an idle state, but it can't just keep on chugging away in the background, doing whatever it wants.

But don't take my word for it; there is no substitute for playing with it yourself. Use the emulator.